# My HttpModule never hits the OnError event when I throw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httpmodule

I created a simple web forms application and created a class library project inside this solution as a project reference.  This class library project is my `HttpModule`.  The idea of this is so I can step into my `HttpModule` code.  Here's what my solution looks like:

[image]

In `Default.aspx.cs`, I threw an exception to see if `OnError` in my `HttpModule` would catch it (which it doesn't catch it - it never hits my breakpoint inside `OnError`):

[image]

Finally, here's my web.config:

[image]

**QUESTION**: Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?  I'm not entirely confident with my web.config entry.  Does the web.config entry look okay?  Could adding this `HttpModule` via a project reference be causing an issue?

Comment: Does Init method get hit?

Comment: Do you have code implementing `Application_Error()` in your `global.asax` file?

Comment: @KarlAnderson I do have code in Application_Error() in global.asax, but I don't want to rely on Global.asax.  This is going to be a drag and drop solution into each of our 300+ web apps and some of our web apps do not have global.asax.  The HttpModule should catch all unhandled exceptions.  You think it's possible it might be handled within global.asax?  Application_Error's code in global.asax is empty.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets No, Init never gets hit either.

Comment: Have you tried to reopen visual studio? Maybe web.config is cached.

Comment: @MikeMarks - my point was not that you should use `Application_Error()` in `global.asax`, but rather that maybe that it is handling your thrown exception, thus your module has no work to do since the `global.asax` module handled it. If you put a break point in the `global.asax` method, does it get hit?

Comment: @KarlAnderson I understand... Yes, Application_Error does get hit.  Then I remove Application_Error and the module still doesn't get hit.  Init isn't even being hit.  It seems like the module itself isn't being loaded.

Comment: it is probably not loaded at all because when you specify type in web config you need to provide class namespace as well. type ="ClassLibrary1.ErrorModule, ClassLibrary1"

Comment: You still need to specify namespace, ErrorModule.ErrorModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your application in Integrated mode? If so, you have to add your http module to the system.webServer/modules configuration section, rather than system.web/httpModules

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
       <add name="ErrorModule" type="ErrorModule, ErrorModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```